# C# LibVLCSharp switching media stream causes HTTP exception

Tags: c#, .net-core, streaming, libvlc, libvlcsharp

We are using [libvlcsharp](/questions/tagged/libvlcsharp) to play a live mp3 network stream in our [xamarin.ios](/questions/tagged/xamarin.ios) app using the following code snippet

```csharp
public bool Play(Uri uri)
{
    Media newMedia = new(this.LibVLC, uri);
    Media? oldMedia = this.VLCMediaPlayer.Media;
    bool success = this.VLCMediaPlayer.Play(newMedia);
    oldMedia?.Dispose();
    return success;
}
```

where `VLCMediaPlayer` is an instance of VLC's `MediaPlayer` class. The code above works and streaming works flawlessly.

**However:**

at some point we need to switch streams (i.e. the original live mp3 stream continues / doesn't technically end and we need to stop streaming it and switch to a different one).

As far as the documentation goes it seems like simply calling `Play()` on a different URL *should* do the trick. The problem is, it doesn't. The original stream stops for a couple of milliseconds and then just continues.

Our code looks something like this:

```csharp
// use our custom Play() wrapper
Play(new Uri("https://whatever.com/some-live-stream.mp3"));

// ... do other stuff

// at some time later switch to a different stream using the same Play() wrapper
Play(new Uri("https://whatever.com/file-stream.mp3"));
```

**The problem:**

VLC doesn't start playback of the `file-stream.mp3` but instead hangs for a couple of milliseconds to then continue playing `some-live-stream.mp3`. Why is this and how do we fix it?

#### Update (seems to be an integration bug):

running libVLC with debug output reveals this:

```text
[00000177e9c21830] main input debug: Creating an input for 'file-stream.mp3'
[00000177e9c21830]playing uri
 main input debug: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB
[00000177e9c21830] main input debug: using timeshift path: C:\Users\EXPUNGED\AppData\Local\Temp
[00000177e9c21830] main input debug: `http://127.0.0.1:5050/file-stream.mp3' gives access `http' demux `any' path `127.0.0.1:5050/file-stream.mp3'
[00000177e9b29350] main input source debug: creating demux: access='http' demux='any' location='127.0.0.1:5050/file-stream.mp3' file='\\127.0.0.1:5050\file-stream.mp3'
[00000177e92e1d60] main demux debug: looking for access_demux module matching "http": 15 candidates
[00000177e92e1d60] main demux debug: no access_demux modules matched
[00000177e904e6d0] main stream debug: creating access: http://127.0.0.1:5050/file-stream.mp3
[00000177e904e6d0] main stream debug:  (path: \\127.0.0.1:5050\file-stream.mp3)
[00000177e904e6d0] main stream debug: looking for access module matching "http": 27 candidates
[00000177e904e6d0] http stream debug: resolving 127.0.0.1 ...
[00000177e904e6d0] http stream debug: outgoing request:
GET /file-stream.mp3 HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:5050
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en_US
User-Agent: VLC/3.0.16 LibVLC/3.0.16
Range: bytes=0-


[00000177e904e6d0] http stream debug: connection failed 
[00000177e904e6d0] access stream error: HTTP connection failure
[00000177e904e6d0] http stream debug: querying proxy for http://127.0.0.1:5050/file-stream.mp3
[00000177e904e6d0] http stream debug: no proxy
[00000177e904e6d0] http stream debug: http: server='127.0.0.1' port=5050 file='/file-stream.mp3'
[00000177e904e6d0] main stream debug: net: connecting to 127.0.0.1 port 5050
[00000177e904e6d0] http stream error: cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:5050
[00000177e904e6d0] main stream debug: no access modules matched
```

*(above snippet starts at when the second `Play()` is called.)*

What immediately catches attention is the `HTTP connection failure`.

However let me expand on our minimal reproducible example. In production we don't only need switch streams once but multiple times. We discontinue the first `some-live-stream.mp3` stream (which runs live 24/7 server side). We then need to switch to `file-stream.mp3` which is a ~10 second long mp3 file. After the file is played we shall continue playing the first stream (`some-live-stream.mp3`).

We therefore wrote a custom `Enqueue()` method in addition to our `Play()` method originally included in this question.

The whole ***relevant*** code of our internal VLC wrapper class therefore actually looks like this:

```csharp
public sealed class MediaService
{
    private readonly LibVLC _libVLC;
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<Uri> _playlist = new();

    public MediaPlayer VLCPlayer { get; }

    internal MediaService(LibVLC libVLC)
    {
        _libVLC = libVLC;
        VLCPlayer = new MediaPlayer(_libVLC);
        VLCPlayer.EndReached += VLCPlayer_EndReached;
    }
    
    public bool Play(Uri uri)
    {
        Media newMedia = new(_libVLC, uri);
        Media? oldMedia = VLCPlayer.Media;
        bool success = VLCPlayer.Play(newMedia);
        oldMedia?.Dispose();
        CurrentUrl = uri.AbsoluteUri;
        return success;
    }

    public bool IsStartingOrPlaying() =>
        VLCPlayer.State is VLCState.Buffering
        or VLCState.Opening
        or VLCState.Playing;
        
    public void Enqueue(Uri uri)
    {
        if (IsStartingOrPlaying())
        {
            _playlist.Enqueue(uri);
        }
        else
        {
            Play(uri);
        }
    }

    private void VLCPlayer_EndReached(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_playlist.TryDequeue(out Uri? result))
        {
            // don't deadlock on VLC callback
            Task.Run(() => Play(result));
        }
    }
}
```

Now to the minimal reproducible example:

the code below fails (i.e. causes the HTTP connection failure)

```csharp
using our.vlc.wrapper;

CoreLoader.Initialize(true);
MediaService mediaService = MediaServiceFactory.GetSharedInstance();

// start streaming the live stream
Task.Run(() => mediaService.Play("http://127.0.0.1:5050/some-live-stream.mp3"))
    // do other stuff...
    .ContinueWith((_) => Thread.Sleep(10000)) 
    // now interrupt the original stream with the mp3 file
    .ContinueWith((_) => mediaService.Play("http://127.0.0.1:5050/file-stream.mp3"))
    // and continue the live stream after mp3 file stream ends
    .ContinueWith((_) => mediaService.Enqueue("http://127.0.0.1:5050/some-live-stream.mp3"));

Console.ReadLine();
```

The HTTP exception when trying to stream `http://127.0.0.1:5050/file-stream.mp3` then obviously causes the "lag" described in the original question and after that the original stream continues as expected.

**HOWEVER**
this code snippet works:

```
using our.vlc.wrapper;

CoreLoader.Initialize(true);
MediaService mediaService = MediaServiceFactory.GetSharedInstance();

// start streaming the live stream
Task.Run(() => mediaService.Play("http://127.0.0.1:5050/some-live-stream.mp3"))
    // do other stuff...
    .ContinueWith((_) => Thread.Sleep(10000)) 
    // now interrupt the original stream with the mp3 file
    .ContinueWith((_) => mediaService.Play("http://127.0.0.1:5050/file-stream.mp3"))
    // another sleep seems to cause no connection failure
    .ContinueWith((_) => Thread.Sleep(10000))
    // call PLAY() instead of ENQUEUE()
    .ContinueWith((_) => mediaService.Play("http://127.0.0.1:5050/some-live-stream.mp3"));

Console.ReadLine();
```

So actually our `Enqueue()` method seems to be the culprit. However I don't see why it's implementation would be an issue and cause a *seemingly random* HTTP connection failure when the `/file-stream.mp3` endpoint is well tested and even works in the second example.

Using some sort of queueing is essential for our project, so we can't just fall back to `Thread.Sleep()` calls as we did in our minimal reproducible examples. How do we fix our `Enqueue()` method and why isn't it working as intended?

#### Update 2

Inspecting traffic during the "HTTP connection failure" using Wireshark shows this:

[image]

We can see the `FIN`, `FIN-ACK`, `ACK` of the terminating TCP connection to the first `/some-live-stream.mp3` get intermingled with the `SYN`, `SYN-ACK`, `ACK` of the HTTP request to `/file-stream.mp3` so it's a bit hard to read but it's clear that the actual HTTP GET **never** gets send so the endpoint at `/file-stream.mp3` is never invoked. It's easier to understand with the following in mind:
Port `5050` is the server providing the streams. Port `20118` is VLC with the first `some-live-stream` connection. Port `20224` is VLC with the second connection to `file-stream.mp3` which is failing and at the bottom you can see a connection from port `20225` initializing which is the continuation of `some-live-stream`.

For some reason VLC immediately terminates the newly established TCP connection for the `/file-stream.mp3` request as soon as it's established (look for the requests going from port `20124->5050`). So VLC **actively terminates the connection :C**.

And then in the last few lines the original `/some-live-stream.mp3` connection is re-established.

So why does VLC fail to even send the HTTP GET for the `/file-stream.mp3` request?

Comment: It should, indeed. Please post a minimal project to reproduce your issue

Comment: share libvlc verbose logs as well

Comment: @cube45 I updated the question accordingly and also provided a bit more context as the bug does not seem to be in the code posted originally.

Comment: When we ask for a minimal repro, it's not minimal in the sense of the number of lines of your Main, but minimal in terms of complexity involved.

You pinpointed your issue to the Enqueue method, but you didn't simplify further.

Comment: @cube45 after oversimplifying in the original question I included all _relevant_ code from our `MediaService` class that would get executed just to be sure :)
So yes you're right it could be simplified further, but it was enough to pinpoint the exact problem. Thank you for taking your time at this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget that `Play()` is not a synchronous method as you might expect. It is a method that posts a stop message to a background thread, and only then starts to play the media.

When you're executing your `IsStartingOrPlaying()` method right after, chances are that the state is not the one that you might have expected, thus calling the second Play()

Comment: you are correct. It seems to be indeed a threading issue. When debugging and breaking in the enqueue method execution flows the intended way hinting that during or shortly after our `IsStartingOrPlaying()` checks the playback state of the vlcplayer changes so the "incorrect" method is executed (Enqueue() directly calls Play() cancelling `file-stream`). 
We'll have to think about thread safety. Thank's for pointing us in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

After @cube45 pointed us in the right direction that the problem at hand was a simple threading issue all we had to do is to introduce basic thread-safety in our `Enqueue()`, `Stop()` and `Play()` methods as can be seen below.

```csharp
public sealed class MediaService
{
    private const int NOT_PLAYING = 0x0;
    private const int PLAYING = 0x1;

    private readonly LibVLC _libVLC;
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<Uri> _playlist = new();

    private volatile int _playbackStatus = NOT_PLAYING;

    public MediaPlayer VLCPlayer { get; }

    internal MediaService(LibVLC libVLC)
    {
        _libVLC = libVLC;
        VLCPlayer = new MediaPlayer(_libVLC);
        VLCPlayer.EndReached += VLCPlayer_EndReached;
    }
    
    public void Enqueue(Uri uri)
    {
        int status = _playbackStatus;

        if (status is PLAYING)
        {
            _playlist.Enqueue(uri);
            if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _playbackStatus, NOT_PLAYING, PLAYING) is NOT_PLAYING)
            {
                // vlc finished while we were enqueuing...
                DequeueAndPlay();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Play(uri);
        }
    }

    public bool Play(Uri uri)
    {
        _ = Interlocked.Exchange(ref _playbackStatus, PLAYING);
        Media newMedia = new(_libVLC, uri);
        Media? oldMedia = VLCPlayer.Media;
        bool success = VLCPlayer.Play(newMedia);
        oldMedia?.Dispose();
        CurrentUrl = uri.AbsoluteUri;
        return success;
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _playbackStatus, NOT_PLAYING, PLAYING) is PLAYING)
        {
            VLCPlayer.Stop();
            if (VLCPlayer.Media is not null)
            {
                Media oldMedia = VLCPlayer.Media;
                VLCPlayer.Media = null;
                oldMedia.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    private void VLCPlayer_EndReached(object sender, EventArgs e) => DequeueAndPlay();

    private void DequeueAndPlay()
    {
        if (_playlist.TryDequeue(out Uri? result))
        {
            Task.Run(() => Play(result));
        }
        else
        {
            _ = Interlocked.Exchange(ref _playbackStatus, NOT_PLAYING);
        }
    }
}
```

while the code above is by no means the "perfect" solution and does not provide thread safety for multiple threads calling `Enqueue()`, `Stop()` or `Play()`, it does however alleviate the exact issue we ran into and it should point anyone encountering a similar problem in the right direction :)